# Acessing variables from one class in another class

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I am stilling doing the same project as my previous question which is trying to simulate particle diffusion. My previous question does not relate to this, beyond still trying to simulate diffusion. I am at stage where I am trying to initiate different regions of diffusivity within the grid, so I have a function to produce a list of lists (coordinates) that can be checked against the coordinates of the particles at each move step to adjust the probability of movement, and as such the diffusivity.

I am using 2 classes; one to initiate the diffusion grid space, grid(), and another to move the particles, atom(). The class atom() does not inherit variables from the class grid(). A region of coordinates called t_space is created in grid() using initiate t_space and I want to access this variable t_space produced in initiate t_space in atom().

My code is very long so I have included what I hope are the relevant bits, and my current attempt at solving this.

The code I hoped would call the t_space variable from grid() in atom() was:

`atom().tspace = grid().t_space`

```
class grid():
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.grid = np.zeros((x,y))
        self.list_of_atoms=[]
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def initiate_t_space(self,t_space_x, t_space_y): 

         self.t_space = []
         for i in range(0,self.t_space_x):
             for j in range(0,self.t_space_y):
                 self.t_space.append([i,j])

 class atom():

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.position=[x,y]
        self.position_tracker=[]
        self.dx=0
        self.dy=0
        # self.tspace = [[11, 42], [11, 43], [11, 44], [11, 45], [11, 46], [11, 47], [11, 48], [11, 49], [11, 50], [11, 51], [11, 52], [11, 53], [11, 54], [11, 55], [11, 56], [11, 57], [11, 58], [12, 38], [12, 39], [12, 40], [12, 41], [12, 42], [12, 43], [12, 44], [12, 45], [12, 46], [12, 47], [12, 48]]
        # self.t_space = []
        # for i in range(0,100):
        #     for j in range(0,200):
        #         self.t_space.append([i,j])
        # print(self.t_space)
        atom().tspace = grid().t_space
```

The commented out code in the atom() class is a previous attempt to initiate t_space in atom(), however it needs to be calculated in grid() as it uses variables from grid().

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does an atom really need to know about the grid that it is within?

Comment: It does i think, so that it can determine the diffusivity at that location

Comment: Then you have a circular dependency... You can update the atom information stored in the grid from the grid class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are not *class attributes* but instead *instance attributes*. `grid()` instantiates your grid class, but you do not assign that instance's `t_space` anywhere (looks like your only way of doing that right now is to call `initiate_t_space(t_space_x, t_space_y)` on that created object).

If `t_space` was intended to be a *class attribute* and be the same for all grids you should create and define it as such. If it is intended to be an *instance attribute* you need to define it for each instance before referencing any instance's `t_space` anywhere.

Regardless, you need to call `initiate_t_space(t_space_x, t_space_y)` to set grid's `t_space`, which you are not doing. In other words, your program never runs the code inside your `insitiate_t_space` function.

[Read more about classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, I didn't mention that the classes are called from a different page of code: `gr=grid(20,20) gr.initiate_t_space(10,10)`

Comment: The atom() is then called later